# Android MotionLayout Transition Listener not called

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to make a slide animation.
For it I use a MotionLayout with a MotionScene containing two ConstraintSet.

The slide animation works fine. However I get an error in the LogCat:

> E/MotionLayout: WARNING NO app:layoutDescription tag

view_slider.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_slider"
app:showPaths="true">

<View
    android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@color/grey26" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

scene_slider.xml:

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:duration="1000">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/btn_slide"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right"
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"/>

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/btn_slide"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

SliderView.kt:

```
class SliderView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MotionLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_slider, this)
    }

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()

        motion_layout.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
            override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
                debug(javaClass.simpleName, "transition completed")
            }

            override fun onTransitionChange(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int, progress: Float) {
                debug(javaClass.simpleName, "progress = $progress")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <com.myapp.utils.views.SliderView
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I might be missing something because there is a layoutDescription to the MotionLayout in code.

How to fix this error and why the TransitionListener callbacks are now called?

Comment: I had also an issue where the TransitionListener was not called when i changed the scene from code, does the animation play/work ? Can We see the code where you set or inflate the View

Comment: Yes the animation work. I can slide the btn_slide. The path is also correclty displayed. I edited my question to show the full code of my custom view.

Comment: Try to replace motion_layout.setTransitionListener()
By this.setTransitionListener(), also, You probable have a reference from an Activity/Fragment, Try to set the TransitionListener from there

Comment: I just tryed your two suggestions but unforntunatly there is the same error in the LogCat and the listener is not called

Comment: Putting the MotionLayout directly into my Fragment doesn't display the error message however the listener is still not called...

Comment: Try to put the addTransitionListener() code in the init block, after the inflate

Comment: Also, can you post your layout where you have your SliderView ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191666/discussion-between-azartys-and-user-one).

Answer (score 1):

```
var motionLayout:MotionLayout?=null
 init {
       motionLayout =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_slider, this)
    }
```

The line above should be equated to a named view..eg val motionLayout.

This named variable should be used in onFinish inflate..i.e

```
  override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()

        motionLayout?.setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
            override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
                debug(javaClass.simpleName, "transition completed")
            }

            override fun onTransitionChange(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int, progress: Float) {
                debug(javaClass.simpleName, "progress = $progress")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MotionLayout did not worked properly in fragments. Try upgrading to beta-2 version.